# How to get first Element of Chrome using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Here is what I currently do to get the first element of a page (or parent element):

```py
first_element = page_or_parent.find_element_by_xpath('//*')
```

The problem I've only just run into recently (Chrome and [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) version 84) is that *sometimes* this throws an exception:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*"}

Calling the same method again usually retrieves the element so I presume the document tree is temporarily unavailable. However, the web driver log doesn't indicate anything strange:

```
[1597164661.317][INFO]: [d88526be26bd6364d1b0ed2dab9d5733] COMMAND FindElement {
"using": "xpath",
"value": "//*"
}
[1597164661.317][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1597164661.317][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1597164661.418][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[1597164661.418][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations. Status: ok
[1597164661.418][INFO]: [d88526be26bd6364d1b0ed2dab9d5733] RESPONSE FindElement ERROR no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.89)
```

My main question is then **how to get the first element reliably**?

Is there a better way than using an XPath as I am doing? I thought about `find_elements_by_xpath()` (plural) but if there's a lot of elements then that's likely to generate a lot of data and run much slower. The only solution I can think of currently is to catch the exception if it occurs, wait/sleep, and then try again but that feels very dirty.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for some time so that the page can load fully and then you can resume your script. or else you can also use the `wait` as shown below -

```
# Import 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

wait.until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "Your XPATH")))
```

Comment: The page is fully loaded when I encounter the problem; I confirmed that the document ready state is `"complete"`

Comment: Have you tried using the `expected_condition` mentioned in the above resolution? If yes then what error you are getting? Same "NoSuchElementException"?

Comment: It would work -- it's the same as sleeping which I've already verified. I think this is a Chrome issue on Linux as it's only come up recently for code that has otherwise run non-stop for 2 years. I'm not going to add sleeps into a helper function for getting the first element; so for now I'm just dealing with the exception